# Rstudio 2023.03.0 Build 386 Not Recognizing Rtools43

Tags: ggplot2, rlang, rtools

My original problem is my attempt to load the ggplot2 package, which failed because my rlang package is too old and is using the binary version instead of the source version. When I attempt to update rlang (or most packages, really,) I usually receive the following message:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Scipio/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

First, I attempted to use the command `install.packages("rlang", type = "source")`, but that still generates the Rtools warning from above and mentions the compilation failed.

When I installed RTools43, I used the installer provided by cran.r-project.org.

At this point, I'd almost like to uninstall my Rstudio and reinstall an older version that would work with the older binary packages, but I'm not sure how far back I would need to go. My version of rlang is 1.0.2 and currently ggplot2 seems to require rlang 1.0.6.

Comment: Current github of ggplot2 states requirement of rlang > 1.1.0, so I'd expect that you'd need that for the future version of ggplot2. I've found that running rstudio as administrator helps if some packages are locked from upgrading.

Comment: Does your version of R match the version of RTools you have installed? If you have RTools43, you should also have R version 4.3 - it looks like you might have 4.0?